# Google places api not showing results for some places

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Hello i am using simple google map places api to get near by atms for users. My client lives around new york and for some strange reason api shows zero results for that place, but works fine near me (pakistan) . I searched for it a little and found out it was google's issue and some other places were also experiencing the same problem. But i never quite found any solution for this.
This is the get call i use

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7128,74.1059&radius=10000000&keyword=atm&key=MY_KEY
```

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Google place nearby search maximum 50,000 meters (31 miles) . if you try enter more than 50,000 it not work proper.

There is another way for find all ATM in a city. google provide **Text Search Requests**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=atm+in+Reno,NV,89501,USA&key={API_KEY}
```

**query = keyword + in + city Name**

for get city name using latitude longitude

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.52963,-119.81380&sensor=true
```

For more information how to get city name using latitude longitude

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding

for more information about how to use Text Search Requests

[https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search)

**OR (second way)**

There is another way for find all ATM in a city.

- Open Google Maps .
- create 10-12 or more points latitude , longitude value to trigger
  request.
- Then use a loop to find all places within these points.
- If you want more appropriate results, increase first trigger points
  for your requests.

**- It is just a logic i created in php.**

```
$triggerPoints = array("lat1,long1", "lat2,long2", "lat3,long3",....);

    foreeach(triggerPoints as $tP){
       $requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$tP&radius=[YOUR_RADIUS_VALUE]&type=[YOUR_TYPE]&name=panera&key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE";
       $results = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
       //Do what you want with response JSON data

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:** Use logical types with your needs.

In my case i used **food** types instead of **supermarket**. In some cases, my local market named **A101** wasnt found under supermarkets. To find which keywords is best for you, you can search below url with your location and map_key and find most common keywords under types for each query and use it.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.986527896166244,%2029.24326049097467&rankby=distance&keyword=a101&key=YOUR_MAP_KEY